# JFileChooser prompt then letter frequency count of text file

Tags: java, file, text, counter, letter

```
    import java.io.File;
    import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class JFileChooser {
       public static void main(String args []) throws Exception{
          JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
          File F = new File("C:/Users/Seth/Desktop/Java");

          chooser.setCurrentDirectory(F);

          chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
       } public String normalizeWord(String word) 
{ 
String result = "";
 for (int i=0; i < word.length(); i+= 1) { 
char c= word.charAt(i); 
if (Character.isLetter(c))
 result += Character.toLowerCase(c); 
} return result;
 } 
} 
}
```

}

My code I'm working on so far. I am trying to make it so that whatever chosen text file from the JFileChooser, I can prompt to count the letter frequency of that text. I have tried combining a separate frequency counter from another String example I have done but it did not compile. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Could you add a little info on the compiler errors you're seeing?

Comment: }
    public String normalizeWord(String word)
    {
        String result = "";
        for (int i=0; i < word.length(); i+= 1)
        {
            char c= word.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isLetter(c))
                result += Character.toLowerCase(c);
        }
        return result;
    }

}

Comment: When I compile the entire code, the prompt shows up but when I click a text file, nothing actually happens. And sorry, I am actually a newbie, I have only been trying to learn for a couple of weeks now. I do not yet know how I would prompt the chosen text file to execute the instruction of counting the letter frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Don't name your class `JFileChooser`. When you create an instance of `JFileChooser`, it's creating an instance of *your* class, not the swing `JFileChooser` (Rule of thumb: don't name classes the same name as ones you already know exist)

Also take a look at [How to use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html). Your going to need to get a File from the `getSelectedFile()` method of `JFileChooser` (after doing a result check). The [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) has a quick simple example you can look at also